# How to include licenses for third-party Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, licensing, mit-license, maven, apache-license

I'm producing a binary distributable for my Java project. I'm releasing it in two ways:

1. Maven Central
2. Zipped distributable on Google code

My project is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license. I use a small number of third-party parties, one of which is MIT licensed. I believe it's my obligation to make users of my project aware of the license contents, based on the following text from the license:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

How am I best to reference this within my source and my distributables? I'm currently thinking:

1. My source files needn't reference anything. They just include my Apache 2.0 boilerplate notice.
2. I add a LICENSE.txt file at the root of my project including the Apache 2.0 license text.
3. For my zipped distributable, I need to also add *something* that indicates a component is MIT licensed. Perhaps a NOTICE file?
4. For my Maven Central distribution, I needn't do anything as my artifact just declares its dependencies, but doesn't actually include them.

Does this seem like a valid plan? If so, can anyone advise how to accomplish point 3.

Answer (score 8):

Using the [Maven License Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/add-third-party-mojo.html), you can generate a text file with all the licenses (`license:add-third-party`). This file can then be included as a resource into your project or your bundled zip.